# The difference between struct and a pointer to struct

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

Suppose I have a struct declared like below:

```
struct node{
  node *next;
  int data;
}
```

And I have a C++ function in a `class Stack` that defines a `push` operation like:

```
void Stack::push(int n){
    node *temp = new node;
    temp->data = n;
    temp->next = top;
    top = temp;

if(topMin == NULL) {
    temp = new node;
    temp->data = n;
    temp->next = topMin;
    topMin = temp;
    return;
}

    if(top->data < topMin->data) {
        temp = new node;
        temp->data = n;
        temp->next = topMin;
        topMin = temp;
    }
    return;
}
```

What's the difference between using

```
node *temp = new node;
```

and

```
temp = new node;
```

In the code above? More specifically, I'm confused about the implication.
If temp is a `pointer(*)`, I understand that

```
temp->data
```

Is just dereferencing the pointer to struct (`(*temp).data`). Similarly, 
what does it mean to be using `temp = new node`?

Is it just a difference of representation?

Comment: both `temp`s are pointers, it actually is the same variable. `node* temp = new node;` is the same as `node* temp; temp = new node;`

Comment: As stated below the first one is a declaration with initialization the second one just the initialization. You should consider reading into some programming / cpp tutorials or books. This will make learning this a bit easier, than just by reading the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
node *temp = new node;
```

is both declaring `temp` and initializing it, while

```
temp = new node;
```

is assigning to a variable that has already been declared, so the compiler already knows what type it is.

Answer (score 0):

The first one declares a new variable in the local scope named "temp", and initializes it to point to a new instance of an object in dynamic scope.

The second one initializes an existing variable named "temp" to point to a new instance of an object in dynamic scope. The existing contents of the variable are destroyed.

Unrelated to your question: the shown code is likely to have a memory leak.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why there would a memory leak? if top==nullptr and it's not accounted for?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. They are the same variable.

Here:

```
node *temp = new node;
```

You have declared `temp` as `node*` and allocated memory using `new` then assign this allocated memory to it.

---

```
 temp = new node;
```

You allocated new memory and assign the memory's address to `temp` which is still a `node*`.